# Bootstrap Popover from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I created a jQuery plugin that loads data from AJAX and then display the data from popover. And when the user click the button again, the button will display the popover instead of reload the data from AJAX.

Here's the code (and this is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/spqdqqhL/)

```
$.fn.myButton = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            var w = $(this);
            w.off('click');
            w.button('loading');
            $.post('/echo/html/', {html: "Content", delay: 1}, function(content) {
                w.button('reset');
                w.popover({content: content})
                    .popover('show');
            });
        });
    });
}

$('.my-button').myButton();
```

The popover loads, but the weird thing is that after the popover being displayed for the first time, I have to click twice to hide the popover. But after that the popover works fine: one click to display and one more to hide so on.

What is that happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.fn.myButton = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        var w = $(this);
        w.off('click');
        w.button('loading');
        $.post('/echo/html/', {html: "Content", delay: 1}, function(content) {
        w.button('reset');
        w.popover({content: content});
            //.popover('show');
          w.trigger( "click" ); // this is not proper way but it is working
        });
    });
    });
}

$('.my-button').myButton();
```